# Libraries and tutorials for HTML5 game for touch devices?

Tags: html, touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML 5 game development tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376727/html-5-game-development-tools)

I am pretty new to game development and want to build a simple game for touch devices using html5 (canvas) and javascript. Then use phonegap to create a native app from HTML+js.

After some search, there are few HTML5 game frameworks like limejs. But I wanted to  know:

1. Which framework is the most popular one for touch devices?
2. Are there any tutorials/how-tos using which I can start with game dev for mobile touch devices in HTML5?

After referring to this list on [Game Engines](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines) I am thinking about two frameworks:
1. [LimeJS](http://www.limejs.com)
2. [Hydra](https://github.com/aduros/hydra)

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siOHh0uzcuY is a good start for an intro. there are resources all over youtube, just use at your own discretion

Comment: Thanks for the link, actually my pain point covers some aspects of HTML5. But anyway, this video will surely help.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a duplicate I answered just two days ago: [HTML 5 game development tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376727/html-5-game-development-tools/7379756#7379756)

Here's a copy/paste of what I wrote:

I have spent a lot of time evaluating different options. [Crafty](http://craftyjs.com/) is my favorite and the one I'm using for my current project. [LimeJS](http://www.limejs.com/) is pretty good but it relies on the [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/) framework, which I'm not a fan of. I also liked both [EaselJS](http://easeljs.com/) and [CasualJS](http://code.google.com/p/casualjs/) a lot.

btw one of the most "professional" options is [Impact](http://impactjs.com/), so you should take a look at that one too. However it doesn't provide many of the features that the various open-source libraries do, and the features Impact provides that the other libraries don't aren't really that valuable. For example, if you need a physics engine for your game (and a platform game probably does) then you can easily integrate [Box2D](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/) on your own. [another Box2D link](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html)

That said, doing things from scratch without using a 3rd-party library is not a bad option. The free ebook [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/canvas.html) does a great job of explaining how the Canvas element works. The thing is, there are a lot of graphics features that a good graphics library will provide that aren't built-in: a display heirarchy allowing Z-order and attaching objects to each other, animation through both tweening objects and spritesheets, mouse events so that you can click on objects, etc..

Comment: +1 Good answer, how does crafty work with touch?

Comment: Well I just played a couple of their demos on my iPhone, so touch input works. However some of their demos didn't load, so perhaps Crafty uses some features that aren't supported on mobile Safari.

Comment: None of the games on their demo page works on my iphone4.

Answer (score 1):

LimeJS. It has a better user community imho. Lots of user support, and forums. You can download lots of source, and be exponentially further along.

Comment: any sample games for limejs? I see some good games in hydra, but limejs has 2 very simple games on its homepage. I am impressed by hydra's demo: http://aduros.emufarmers.com/html5/snowbound/ works like a charm on iphone.